# Python/Pygame: subclass not finding variable

Tags: class, variables, python-3.x, pygame

Probably not the right title but I've no idea how else to formulate it.
I'm trying to calculate stats based on flexible values, specifically HP & MP and return the values so they can be printed on the screen. I've tried making a separate class for the stats and calling on that, changing it to self.HP in both the stats as well as when it's called upon but nothing seems to work and I can't figure out how to fix it.
I know it's a lot of code but could someone have a look at it, please?

E1: After copying the right code here (I'm an idiot -_-') and changing HP back to self.HP the program goes completely bananas... It literally runs itself to death.

```
import formulae
from formulae import *

characters = {"1":battle_maiden("Hibikime")}
enemies = {"a":enemy("Enemy")}

while characters["1"].alive and enemies["a"].alive:
    print
    for charactersKey, in sorted(characters.keys()):
        print(characters[charactersKey])
```

Code that's in formulae.py:

```
class character(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.alive = True
        self.Hit = 10
        self.Dodge = 0
        self.Lv = 1

    def __str__(self):
        if self.alive:
            return "%s (%i HP, %i MP)" % (self.name, self.HP, self.MP)
        else:
            return "%s (DEAD)" % self.name

    def attack(self, enemy):
        print(self.name, "attacks", enemy.name)
        enemy.hit()

    def hit(self):
        self.HP -= self.Atk
        print(self.name, "is hit! (",self.Atk,")")
        if self.HP <= 0:
            self.die()

    def die(self):
        self.alive = False
        print(self.name, "died.")


class enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.alive = True
        self.HP = 100
        self.MP = 20
        self.M_Atk = 10
        self.Atk = 30
        self.Def = 5
        self.M_Def = 5
        self.Hit = 10
        self.Dodge = 0

    def __str__(self):
        if self.alive:
            return "%s (%i HP, %i MP)" % (self.name, self.HP, self.MP)
        else:
            return "%s (DEAD)" % self.name

    def attack(self, enemy):
        print(self.name, "attacks", enemy.name)
        enemy.hit()

    def hit(self):
        self.HP -= self.Atk
        print(self.name, "is hit! (",self.Atk,")")
        if self.HP <= 0:
            self.die()

    def die(self):
        self.alive = False
        print(self.name, "died.")


##SUBCLASSES FOR CHARACTERS##

class battle_maiden(character):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(battle_maiden, self).__init__(self)
        classHP = 80
        classMP = 5
        Vitality = 10
        Wisdom = 3
        Intelligence = 2
        Strength = 15
        Defense = 5
        Dexterity = 15
        Agility = 2

        self.HP = (classHP + (self.Lv*5) + (Vitality *(self.Lv *0.3)))
        self.MP = (classMP + (self.Lv*2) + (Wisdom *(self.Lv *0.2)))
        Atk = (Strength * (self.Lv*0.2))
        M_Atk = (Intelligence * (self.Lv*0.2))
        Def = (Defense + (self.Lv*1.5) + (Defense*0.1))
        M_Def = (Intelligence + (self.Lv*1.5) + (Intelligence*0.1))
```

The error I'm getting:
return "%s (%i HP, %i MP)" % (self.name, self.HP, self.MP)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Is there code for battle_maiden elsewhere?

Comment: You also don't seem to be initializing self.HP for your characters--at least not for your character base class or for your mage. You do it for enemies.

Comment: My bad, I took a part out of the code and then I copied the wrong one from the other file lol. Lemme change that.
Also I changed it to self.HP because HP gave me the error that it wasn't globally declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is first, double importing is naughty so don't do it ;)

And fixing this is pretty simple, you just have to replace replace

```
super(battle_maiden, self).__init__(self)
```

with

```
character.__init__(self, name)
```

As of why, try to find out on your own. If you can't in 30 minutes, ask in comment and I will spoil it ;)

Comment: What about `super(battle_maiden, self).__init__(name)`? There's no need to get rid of the super(), is it?

Comment: No you don't have to, that is correct (although which version is better is a religious debate I won't get into). You simply have to fix the variable so it will be passing name, not instance of self ;).

Comment: Well I put that in because I was looking at a guide and trying to apply it to this, it specifically stated to add the super() to it. It sounded logical...

Comment: You can use super just fine, if that is what tutorial suggests then stick with it. Just make sure to type the arguments right next time ;)

Comment: Actually the only thing I changed on that is the subclass name. The rest is literally copy pasted from the tutorial. :)
However, changing the self to name did fix it. Although I have to admit I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: Well, name is a string, name for that character while self passed entire class in it's place. 
So if you passed name, then self.name in the parent would be a string. 
But if you passed self, then self.name would be instance of self. And if self.name is instance of self then returning self.name would enter an endless loop (because def __str__(self): returns self.name, which now is not a string, but instance of self which when asked to converts to string returns self.name which is instance of self which when aksed to convert to string... you get the drill).

Comment: It sounds incredibly complicated but it's actually very simple. :p Thanks for explaining.